# Quick insert TODO line

Tags: intellij-idea, android-studio

Is it possible to setup IDEA to be able to quick insert `// TODO` lines? For example keybinding or code completion pattern? I didn't find anything.

Comment: Have you tried to use live templates for this?

Comment: No I haven't. Reading about it now. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out the Live Templates feature of IntelliJ. I hope it'll satisfy your needs.

Here's a [tutorial video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZxaVNGSax80) on how to create one.

Answer (score 10):

Since 1.3 Android Studio ships with a set of live templates.
One of which does exactly what you want.

In order to activate it, simply type `todo` followed by a tab. Also works with `fixme` and `stopship`.

Comment: as of v2020.3, for me it worked with typing st + pressing tab

Answer (score 2):

Live Template fixed my problem.
I wanted to add a custom todo comment in intellij with my initials and date so i did this:

// TODO: $date$ [name] $todo$

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQPxZ.png)

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug8eJ.png)